# XSL <for-each> and 'following-sibling'

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to transform an XML file containing people into CSV. 
Some of those people have the same id. 
For those who have the same id, I am trying to place their name into a different column ("variant") than the first occurrence ("title").
There is also a column name `="id_type_nom"` with a value of `1` for the first occurrence and a value of `8` for the next ones.

Here is what looks the XML input like :

```
<database name="bude">
  <table name="noms_personnages">
    <column name="nom">Giovanni Battista Baliani</column>
    <column name="id_personnage">6798</column>
    <column name="id_type_nom">1</column>
  </table>
  <table name="noms_personnages">
    <column name="nom">Giambattista Baliani</column>
    <column name="id_personnage">6798</column>
    <column name="id_type_nom">8</column>
  </table>
</database>
```

Here is what looks like my XSL for now

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
exclude-result-prefixes="xd"
version="2.0">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>



<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>"title","variant"
    </xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="//table/column[@name='nom'][following-sibling::column[@name='id_type_nom'] = '1']">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>","</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select=".[following::column[@name='id_type_nom'] = '8']"/><xsl:text>"
        </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

With

> .[following::column[@name='id_type_nom'] = '8']`

I only get the name of the first person, but I haven't succeeded to get the name of the next person.

Here is the output I get :

```
"title","variant"
"Giovanni Battista Baliani","Giovanni Battista Baliani"
```

Here is the output I'm looking for

```
"title","variant"
"Giovanni Battista Baliani","Giambattista Baliani"
```

Many thanks if anyone has a clue!

Comment: This is confusing, especial because your xslt example is not valid xslt e.g. `select=".[not( preceding::column = column )]"`. Please provide a working example, expected output and current output.

Comment: What is the expected output for names with 2 or more variants? And for names with no variants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you adopt a slightly different approach:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="variants" match="table[column[@name='id_type_nom']=8]" use="column[@name='id_personnage']" />

<xsl:template match="/database">
    <xsl:text>"title","variant"&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="table[column[@name='id_type_nom']=1]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table">
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="column[@name='nom']"/>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('variants', column[@name='id_personnage'])">
        <xsl:text>,"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="column[@name='nom']"/>
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```